# Assigning the Id for the combo box drop down from the model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net MVC web application, In the create view I have loaded the combo box list values from the database table.

In the controller, I have used,

```
 ViewBag.Citizen_Country_Id = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Country_Name");
```

and in the view,

```
<div class="form-group row"> 
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Citizen_Country_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" }) 
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <span class="asterisk_input"></span> 
     @Html.DropDownList("Citizen_Country_Id", null, "Select Country", new { @class = "form-control js-dropdown " }) 
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Citizen_Country_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
</div>
```

In the create view I can select the value from the list and submit the value to the controller.

When this comes to Edit, I pass the selected value from the controller to the edit view. But it doesn't select the value related to the Id and show it. It's again loaded with the values and the default `Select the Value from the List` shows.

For Example, If I choose Australia from the combo box and submits. In Edit view I want to select the Country Id from the drop-down and default show with Australia in the combo box.

Any Ideas on how to do that?   `I also used the same HTML code for the **Edit** View`

Comment: U need to pass back the value from the viewbag e.g. Viewbag. CountryId = new SelectList((from s in db.country Select new {Id = s. Id, Des = s.desription}),Id,Des,Model.CountryId);    model. CountryId refers to the dedaultvalue.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong Thanks. from your answer I wrote ``ViewBag.Citizen_Country_Id = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Country_Name", customer.Country_Id);`` and worked. Thanks

Comment: It is always the problem for Mvc5 and below. For mvc core, we can simply put @value = Model.CountryId in the dropdown Html element

Comment: @Dev Beginner, good to see you found the answer. Can you write it as the answer post instead of comment? You may refer to [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, The answer to the question is

```
ViewBag.Citizen_Country_Id = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Country_Name", customer.Country_Id);
```